# Merge N lines into a line for mysql output

Tags: bash, parsing, awk

I have slow query mysql output with 2 columns separated by '|' but out of that 1 column in sql query text which is multi line. Ex,

```
| query_id | query_text| 
| Select_table1_59711_9a3cf39f0a4a0fae | SELECT COUNT(*),COUNT(`stock_exchange`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`stock_exchange`),COUNT(`display_domain`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`display_domain`),COUNT(`products_and_services_lower`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`products_and_services_lower`),COUNT(`nc_hash`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`nc_hash`),COUNT(`naics`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`naics`),COUNT(`slintel_sector`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`slintel_sector`),COUNT(`employee_range`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`employee_range`),COUNT(`cb_link`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`cb_link`),COUNT(`fgic_quality_score`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`fgic_quality_score`),COUNT(`annual_revenue`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`annual_revenue`),COUNT(`revenue_range`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`revenue_range`),COUNT(`facebook`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`facebook`),COUNT(`youtube`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`youtube`),COUNT(`industry_deprecated`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`industry_deprecated`),COUNT(`mcd_name_exclusion_removed_date`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`mcd_name_exclusion_removed_date`),COUNT(`industry_v2_ranked`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`industry_v2_ranked`),COUNT(`franchisee_parent_id`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`franchisee_parent_id`),COUNT(`dnc_hash`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`dnc_hash`),COUNT(`is_display_quality`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`is_display_quality`),COUNT(`usefulness_score`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`usefulness_score`),COUNT(`industry_v2`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`industry_v2`),COUNT(`is_mutable`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`is_mutable`),COUNT(`fortune_1000`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`fortune_1000`),COUNT(`employee_count`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`employee_count`),COUNT(`num_country_records`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`num_country_records`),COUNT(`preferred_id`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`preferred_id`) FROM `table1_59711` OPTION (INTERPRETER_MODE=LLVM) /*stats_collection_query*/ |
| Select_table3_60867__et_al_d7a90531f56de418 | select
 id,
 name
 from
 table3
 where
 id in (^) |
| Select_country_39040 | SELECT
 table2.mid AS mid,
 table2.logo AS company_logo_url,
 table2.name AS name,
 table2.display_domain AS website,
 table2.employee_range AS employee_range,
 table2.industry_v2_ranked AS industry_v2_ranked,
 table2.city AS city,
 table2.state AS state,
 table2.country AS country,
 table2.phone AS phone_number,
 table2.products_and_services AS products_and_services,
 table2.naics AS naics,
 table2.sic AS sic,
 table2.slintel_company_type AS type,
 table2.year_founded AS year_founded,
 table2.total_funding_raised_range AS total_funding_raised_range,
 table2.revenue_range AS revenue_range,
 table2.linkedin AS linkedin,
 table2.facebook AS facebook,
 table2.twitter AS twitter,
 table2.usefulness_score AS usefulness_score
FROM table2 AS table2
WHERE
 table2.mid IN (
 SELECT
 s2_optimizer_hint_wrap.mid AS mid) |
```

Here only query_text column is multi line. I want to get query text as part of one line for better parsing and analysis like,

```
| query_id | query_text| 
| Select_table1_59711_9a3cf39f0a4a0fae | SELECT COUNT(*),COUNT(`stock_exchange`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`stock_exchange`),COUNT(`display_domain`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`display_domain`),COUNT(`products_and_services_lower`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`products_and_services_lower`),COUNT(`nc_hash`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`nc_hash`),COUNT(`naics`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`naics`),COUNT(`slintel_sector`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`slintel_sector`),COUNT(`employee_range`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`employee_range`),COUNT(`cb_link`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`cb_link`),COUNT(`fgic_quality_score`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`fgic_quality_score`),COUNT(`annual_revenue`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`annual_revenue`),COUNT(`revenue_range`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`revenue_range`),COUNT(`facebook`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`facebook`),COUNT(`youtube`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`youtube`),COUNT(`industry_deprecated`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`industry_deprecated`),COUNT(`mcd_name_exclusion_removed_date`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`mcd_name_exclusion_removed_date`),COUNT(`industry_v2_ranked`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`industry_v2_ranked`),COUNT(`franchisee_parent_id`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`franchisee_parent_id`),COUNT(`dnc_hash`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`dnc_hash`),COUNT(`is_display_quality`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`is_display_quality`),COUNT(`usefulness_score`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`usefulness_score`),COUNT(`industry_v2`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`industry_v2`),COUNT(`is_mutable`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`is_mutable`),COUNT(`fortune_1000`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`fortune_1000`),COUNT(`employee_count`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`employee_count`),COUNT(`num_country_records`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`num_country_records`),COUNT(`preferred_id`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`preferred_id`) FROM `table1_59711` OPTION (INTERPRETER_MODE=LLVM) /*stats_collection_query*/ |
| Select_table3_60867__et_al_d7a90531f56de418 | select id, name from table3 where id in (^) |
| Select_country_39040 | SELECT table2.mid AS mid, table2.logo AS company_logo_url, table2.name AS name, table2.display_domain AS website, table2.employee_range AS employee_range, table2.industry_v2_ranked AS industry_v2_ranked, table2.city AS city, table2.state AS state, table2.country AS country, table2.phone AS phone_number, table2.products_and_services AS products_and_services, table2.naics AS naics, table2.sic AS sic, table2.slintel_company_type AS type, table2.year_founded AS year_founded, table2.total_funding_raised_range AS total_funding_raised_range, table2.revenue_range AS revenue_range, table2.linkedin AS linkedin, table2.facebook AS facebook, table2.twitter AS twitter, table2.usefulness_score AS usefulness_score FROM table2 AS table2 WHERE table2.mid IN ( SELECT mid AS mid) |
```

I tried to achieve this with below awk command but could not get it. Can anybody help?

```
BEGIN{RS="\^|"; FS = "|"}NF>1{print gensub(/\n/," ","g")}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '{rec=rec (/^\|/ ? sep : "") $0; sep=ORS} END{print rec}' file
| query_id | query_text|
| Select_table1_59711_9a3cf39f0a4a0fae | SELECT COUNT(*),COUNT(`stock_exchange`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`stock_exc`),COUNT(`display_domain`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`display_domain`),COUNT(`products_and_services_lower`),APPROX_COISTINCT(`products_and_services_lower`),COUNT(`nc_hash`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`nc_hash`),COUNT(`naics`),APPROX_COISTINCT(`naics`),COUNT(`slintel_sector`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`slintel_sector`),COUNT(`employee_range`),APPROX_CDISTINCT(`employee_range`),COUNT(`cb_link`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`cb_link`),COUNT(`fgic_quality_score`),APPROX_CDISTINCT(`fgic_quality_score`),COUNT(`annual_revenue`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`annual_revenue`),COUNT(`revenue_ranAPPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`revenue_range`),COUNT(`facebook`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`facebook`),COUNT(`youtube`),APPRONT_DISTINCT(`youtube`),COUNT(`industry_deprecated`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`industry_deprecated`),COUNT(`mcd_name_sion_removed_date`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`mcd_name_exclusion_removed_date`),COUNT(`industry_v2_ranked`),APPROX_CDISTINCT(`industry_v2_ranked`),COUNT(`franchisee_parent_id`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`franchisee_parent_id`),COUNT(hash`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`dnc_hash`),COUNT(`is_display_quality`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`is_display_quality`),(`usefulness_score`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`usefulness_score`),COUNT(`industry_v2`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`indust`),COUNT(`is_mutable`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`is_mutable`),COUNT(`fortune_1000`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`fortune_1,COUNT(`employee_count`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`employee_count`),COUNT(`num_country_records`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINum_country_records`),COUNT(`preferred_id`),APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(`preferred_id`) FROM `table1_59711` OPTION (INTEER_MODE=LLVM) /*stats_collection_query*/ |
| Select_table3_60867__et_al_d7a90531f56de418 | select id, name from table3 where id in (^) |
| Select_country_39040 | SELECT table2.mid AS mid, table2.logo AS company_logo_url, table2.name AS name, table2.dy_domain AS website, table2.employee_range AS employee_range, table2.industry_v2_ranked AS industry_v2_ranked, tacity AS city, table2.state AS state, table2.country AS country, table2.phone AS phone_number, table2.products_andices AS products_and_services, table2.naics AS naics, table2.sic AS sic, table2.slintel_company_type AS type, tabear_founded AS year_founded, table2.total_funding_raised_range AS total_funding_raised_range, table2.revenue_rangrevenue_range, table2.linkedin AS linkedin, table2.facebook AS facebook, table2.twitter AS twitter, table2.usefulscore AS usefulness_scoreFROM table2 AS table2WHERE table2.mid IN ( SELECT s2_optimizer_hint_wrap.mid AS mid) |
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following GNU `awk` solution. It basically sets `RS`(record separator) as `(^|\n)\\| Select_` to get the required values and then print values as per need.

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)\\| Select_' '
RT{
   gsub(/\n/,"")
   if(++count>1){
     sub(/^\n/,"",RT)
     print RT $0
   }
   else{
     print
   }
   rt=RT
}
END{
   if($0){
     gsub(/\n/,"")
     sub(/^\n/,"",rt)
     print rt $0
   }
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: nice solution thnx for that ++ 